# How can I get the lighting right for a taxidermy shoulder mount against the wall?

Tags: lighting, studio-lighting

I'm looking to take some photographs of a taxidermy shoulder mount ([link to a mount like I'm talking about](http://www.thetaxidermystore.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/m/u/mule-deer-shoulder-mount-for-sale-_16520-_-the-taxidermy-store.jpg)), and I'm having a hard time getting the lighting right. I'd like to get a rim light behind it to highlight the fur on the ears and the antlers. The problem is it's mounted directly on the wall, and that leaves me with very little space.

Has anyone ever come across this when doing portrait photography? Any tips or equipment suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

I'm not trying to reproduce the linked photo.  I'm trying to take a nice photos of a deer that is mounted to a wall in a similar way.

Comment: can it be unmounted from the wall?

Comment: It could be, I'd have to rig something so it extended off of the wall.  I figure I could get it a foot or two away.  I could also mount it on some sort of post, but then there would be something sticking out the bottom, and I'd have to photoshop it out.

Comment: Are you able to mount anything behind it? To me, the linked photo feels very flat. I'd try putting a speedlight on the buck's neck to either add a rim light or something. Getting it further from the background would definitely help.

Answer (score 1):

Where the ceiling meets the wall you could mount a mirror, or a highly reflective board, and bounce a light on it (a lamp with a fresnel lens or a theatrical type ellipsoidal projector would be ideal, so that you can keep the light from spilling all over the place). Depending on the angle used to mount it on the wall or ceiling, and the light placement you should be able to get illumination from an place where is physically impossible to fit a light source.